# What is the rank of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-rank

From linear algebra we know that the rank of a matrix is the maximal number of linearly independent columns or rows in a matrix. So, for a *matrix*, the rank can be determined by simple row reduction, determinant, etc. However, I am wondering how the concept of a rank applies to a single vector, i.e., $\mathbf{v} = [a, \ b, \ c]^{\top}$. My intuition suggests that the rank must be equal to 1, but I'm not even sure if it is defined for a vector. Can anyone help shed some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Warning: not all vectors have the form of a column of numbers. This is not how we define things in mathematics (any more). A vector is simply an element in a vector space. A vector space is defined axiomatically. A vector in it has no a-priori shape or form.

Comment: You may consider $1$ for a non-zero vector, $0$ for the zero vector.

Comment: See thread below why that would not be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A vector is an element in a vector space. As such, it has no rank. A matrix, in the context of linear algebra, is interesting because it represents a linear transformation between vector spaces. It's the linear transformation we care about, not the rectangle of numbers we call a matrix. A linear transformation has a rank and that rank is the dimension of the image of the linear transformation. It's an interesting concept since it's a measurement of how large the linear transformation is. It just so happens that when the linear transformation is represented as a matrix the rank can be computed in various convenient ways.

With this in mind, the superficial resemblance of a vector to a matrix is misleading. A vector is not a representation of a linear transformation between vector spaces. For that reason, it simply makes no sense to ask what the rank of a vector is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am still a bit puzzled: In the special case that a linear transformation reduces to single $1\times p$ matrix  (I will not use the word $\textit{vector}$ for the reasons you have outlined above), does it still not make any sense to talk about rank of this simple transformation? That is, does the rank of a nonzero $1\times p$ matrix still not have any rank?

Comment: the rank of a $1 \times p$ matrix is defined just like the rank of any matrix. It's $0$ if all entries are $0$ and $1$ otherwise. It simply has nothing to do with the rank of a vector, nor should the superficial resemblance of this matrix to a vector lead one to any fantasies about rank of a vector making any kind of sense.

Comment: Great, thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: *"A vector is not a representation of a linear transformation between vector spaces."*  In fact, a vector may represent a linear form.

Comment: @Joey There is a connection between a $1 \times p$ matrix and the vector $\mathbf v$ that would be represented by this same matrix: for any vector $\mathbf v$, this associated map is the transformation $T: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^p$ given by $T(t) = t\,\mathbf v$. The rank of this linear transformation is $1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann the rank of that transformation is at most $1$. Regardless, this only works if you choose the standard basis in $\mathbb R ^p$ and the basis $1$ in $\mathbb R$ to represent the linear transformation. If the vector you start with is in an infinite dimensional vector space, then this is no longer possible. So, this sort of observation (without being explicit about the choice of bases) reinforces the confusion between a vector/transformation and its representation as a column/matrix. There is no such thing as "the matrix representing a transformation". You need to specify bases.

Comment: @Ittay There is such a thing as "the matrix representing a transformation" in the very common case that our vector space $\Bbb R^p$ or is otherwise equipped with a canonical basis. It is true that infinite dimensional spaces are problematic, which is why most discussions of introductory linear algebra avoid them altogether. Yes, my explanation misses some subtleties about the wider context (beyond $\Bbb R^p$), but insisting that every explanation of elementary linear algebra should be geared towards this broader context serves only to alienate new students.

Comment: @BenGrossmann my main aim is to emphasise the difference between a transformation and its representations. I know that this is usually avoided in many approaches to elementary algebra but that does not mean it's a good thing. The apparent simplicity of saying "a vector is just a column of numbers and a matrix is just a rectangle of numbers" is a double-edged sword. Regardless, your claim that $\mathbb R^p$ has a canonical basis is incorrect. There is nothing canonical about the standard basis. It's merely a very useful one, hence naming it standard. But it is not canonical.

Comment: @Ittay It is certainly the case that the adjective "canonical" is often used for the standard basis, though I agree that depending on your definition of the term "canonical," this usage could be problematic. Whatever adjective you use, the fact of the matter is that there is that there is a default interpretation of an $m \times n$ matrix as a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. The statement that there is "no such thing as 'the matrix representing a transformation'" blatantly disregards this fact.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It does not blatantly disregard this fact. Rather it blatantly refuses to adhere to that practice. It is a mirage that a matrix represents a transformation. An artefact of a desire to oversimplify teaching. In practice, a transformation is first obtained (rarely already as a matrix) and then *suitable* bases are sought in order to conveniently represent that transformation as a matrix. So, it's exactly the other way around: first comes the transformation, then come the bases, and then the representing matrix. Even that is true only if you insist to work with coordinates.

Comment: very nice answer emphasizing the fact that the concept of "rank" should be reserved specifically to linear transformations, and that a vector by itself is not a linear transformation (unless of course one unnecessarily assumes finite-dimensionality to identify $V\cong V^{**}$... but most likely if a student is capable of understanding this isomorphism more than likely they wouldn't have this question). Also, while matrices are extremely useful for computational purposes, they're a conceptual nightmare

Comment: @Ittay Matrices (along with row/column-vectors, should we want to insist that these are distinct entities) form a system of mathematical objects that are equipped with scalar-multiplication and matrix-multiplication. These objects can be studied and discussed in and of themselves. It is a mirage that linear algebra can only "properly" be done within the formalism of vector spaces and linear transformations. This is an artifact of a desired to oversimplify the discussion of mathematics, to make everything more "elegant."

Comment: ... especially if the student isnt repeatedly told that a matrix by itself has not much conceptual significance. And having TAed some physics courses several times (classical mechanics, E&M), it was clear that so many of their issues regarding coordinate transformations essentially boiled down to the fact that they do not appreciate/have not been told the fact that everything is being done with respect to a basis (usually the "standard basis"), which further added to the confusion when changing bases

Comment: @Ittay If you want to speak of "practice," there are many situations in which the reverse occurs: we are given a matrix of measurements, and by interpreting this matrix as a suitable object (sometimes as a bilinear form, sometimes as a linear transformation), we gain information about the data by pointing to a property of the induced object. As classic examples of this, see "principal-component analysis" and the solution to the "orthogonal Procrustes problem"

Comment: @BenGrossmann even if you want to concentrate on vector spaces and linear transformations of a particular form (say only consider $\mathbb R^n$) it is still not the case that there is a canonical basis. The whole point of diagonalisation is to represent a given matrix in terms of (usually) the non-standard basis. So, the standard basis is not only not canonical but also mainly useful due to a particular syntactic representation of vector spaces. If you call that a question of elegance and choose to portray that negatively, well, ok, I guess.

Comment: @BenGrossmann re: PCA and the like, I'm not saying there is no value to the standard basis and to columns and matrices as tools. My objection is to confusingly identifying things that should not be identified, particularly when it is done so for pedagogical reasons that while meaning well breed confusion.

Comment: @Ittay To put to rest the "canonical basis" thing: my usage is common, as is explained in the associated [wiki page:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis) "in a coordinate space, and more generally in a free module, it refers to the standard basis defined by the Kronecker delta". I am not implying that elegance is bad. I am implying that the perception of elegance is subjective, and that this perceived elegance often comes at a cost. As I said earlier, this cost in many cases is ease of discussion or explanation.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm happy to put the canonical basis to rest (particularly since it does not exist). I was using the term canonical in the mathematical sense. As for elegance, I did not argue from elegance. I agree that elegance is in the eye of the beholder. My objection is to teaching certain concepts in a way that leads to confusion rather than clarity. Asking what is the rank of a vector is a question that, if linear algebra is taught correctly, would never be asked. Why would one expect a concept of transformations to apply to vectors?

Comment: It's as if I'd ask, in the context of functions, whether the notion of "a function being injective" can be generalised to numbers? Can "5 is injective" be given meaning? Well, such a question would not be entertained by any student since it's very clear that a function $f\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is very different that the numbers in its (co)domain. The problem with linear algebra taught via matrices is that this distinction disappears. Taking the time to emphasise that is important and avoids confusion.

Comment: @Ittay I don't want to drag this discussion out. Perhaps it suffices to say that both of our approaches to pedagogy have their proponents and what prompted me to take it this far is your unfounded insistence that your way of doing things is the only correct one.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm sure we've given enough food for thought to anybody following this thread. I'm happy to stop here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another definition of rank of a matrix is the dimension of the vector space spanned by its column, so any non-zero vector spans a space of dimension 1.

Comment: It is not true to claim that a vector is a matrix with just one column. In the vector space of all continuous functions on the reals (just as an example) a vector is a continuous function. Not a matrix.

Comment: @IttayWeiss You are right. I edited consequently.

Comment: But you are still implying that a vector is a matrix of a special form. It's irrelevant that a vector spans a subspace of dimension at most 1. The vector is not a representation of a transformation, so it's got no rank.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I disagree. In what sense does a single non-zero vector in a high dimensional vector space have full rank? If anything, all this is saying is that a single vector is linearly independent unless it is the zero vector. That is not a new concept and it has nothing to do with rank. What is being suggested is superficially a natural extension but it ignores the fact that rank is a concept defined for a linear transformation, not to vectors at all. Rows, columns, and rectangles of numbers are merely representations of vectors and linear transformations. And not even all of them.

Comment: Moreover, saying "an extension of rank from matrices to vectors" already is problematic. An extension suggests that someone vector is more general than matrix. That is manifestly incorrect. The two are completely different concepts. It's just so happens that under a particular representations it appears that a vector is a special form of matrix.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, there are several reasons to refuse this generalisation. Firstly, it's not a generalisation (the vector concept does not extend the matrix notion). Second, it does not capture anything other than "a single vector is linearly independent unless it is zero" so it gives nothing new. Thirdly, it adds to the confusion where some people think a vector is a matrix of a special form where in fact the two notions are completely distinct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112603/discussion-between-ittay-weiss-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @IttayWeiss: sorry, I don't adhere to this dogmatism.